# Limit of a random walk with zero mean

Tags: probability-theory

$(Y_n)$ is a sequence of independent random variables with
$$P(Y_n = 2^n-1)= 2^{-n},\; P(Y_n = -1) = 1 - 2^{-n}$$
I'm investigating their partial sums
$$X_n = \sum^n_{k=1} Y_k$$
Now, I am to check that the sequence $(X_n)$ does not fulfill the  assumptions of the martingale convergence theorems through showing that $X_n \stackrel{a.s.}\to -\infty$

Now, checking that this indeed is a martingale is simple. $E[Y_n]=(2^n-1)2^{-n} - (1-2^{-n}) = 1-2^{-n}-1+2^{-n}=0$ and thanks to that the martingale property is satisfied (I do not believe showing the working would help the question)

When it comes to proving that $X_n \stackrel{a.s.}\to -\infty$, however, I've been now unsuccesful for quite a while now. I'd appreciate a **hint** in the right direction (as I'd still like to come up with the solution myself, if at all possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: What does Borel-Cantelli say about the number of times $Y_n > 0$?

Comment: Ah, dammit. Well, thank you :)